# Show deleted file with Java

Tags: java

I have to write a Java program which shows deleted files from a computer and recycle bin. Just show deleted files, not recover them.
Please, how can I proceed ?

Thanks.

Comment: Recycle bin/Trash is just a directory like others

Comment: Do you mean that you want to list what's *in* the recycle bin?  That's just a directory, you can list its contents.  Or do you mean you want to list what's *been previously emptied from* the recycle bin and actually *deleted* at the file system level?  That sounds considerably more involved, and may start with reading up on the file system(s) being targeted as not all will handle deletes the same way.  At that point the question becomes what actual information you're looking for, because it becomes increasingly likely that information *doesn't exist*.

Comment: Please provide us with the code you have already written.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To make it easier for other users to help you, please include some code to show [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), preferably in the form of a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Listen_Directory {

private final WatchService watcher ;
private final Map<WatchKey,Path> keys;
private final boolean recursive;
private boolean trace = false;
private static PrintWriter writeEvent = null ;
static Interface interf = new Interface();
//private static List<String> listDeletedFiles = new ArrayList<>();



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
    return (WatchEvent<T>)event;
}



/**
 * Register the given directory with the WatchService
 */
private void register(Path dir) throws IOException {
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher,ENTRY_CREATE,ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);

    if (trace) {
        Path prev = keys.get(key);
        if (prev == null) {
            System.out.format("register: %s\n", dir);
        } else {
            if (!dir.equals(prev)) {
                System.out.format("update: %s -> %s\n", prev, dir);
            }
        }
    }
    keys.put(key, dir);
}

/**
 * Register the given directory, and all its sub-directories, with the
 * WatchService.
 */
private void registerAll(final Path start) throws IOException {
    // register directory and sub-directories
    try  {
    Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, 
                BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException
        {
            register(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
    } catch (AccessDeniedException exc){

    } catch (FileSystemException ex){

    }
}

/**
 * Creates a WatchService and registers the given directory
 */
Listen_Directory(Path dir, boolean recursive) throws IOException {

    this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    this.keys = new HashMap<WatchKey,Path>();
    this.recursive = recursive;

    if (recursive) {
        System.out.format("Scanning %s ...\n", dir);
        registerAll(dir);
        System.out.println("Done_"+dir);
    } else {
        register(dir);
    }

    // enable trace after initial registration
    this.trace = true;
}

/**
 * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
 */
void processEvents() {
    for (;;) {

        // wait for key to be signalled
        WatchKey key;
        try {
            key = watcher.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            return;
        }

        Path dir = keys.get(key);
        if (dir == null) {
            System.err.println("WatchKey not recognized!!");
            continue;
        }

        for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

             System.out.format("%s: \n", event.kind().name());

            // TBD - provide example of how OVERFLOW event is handled


            // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
            WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
            Path name = ev.context();
            Path child = dir.resolve(name);

            // print out event
            System.out.format("%s: %s\n", event.kind().name(), child);

            createDataLink();

            String fiche = checkIfIsInRecycleBin( child.toString());

            writeEvent.append(fiche+ "\n");
            writeEvent.flush();

            interf.jTextAreaPaths.append( fiche+"\n");

            if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                continue;
            }
            // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then
            // register it and its sub-directories
            if (recursive /*&& (kind == ENTRY_CREATE)*/) {
                try {
                    if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                        registerAll(child);
                    }
                } catch (IOException x) {
                    // ignore to keep sample readbale
                }
            }
        }

        // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
        boolean valid = key.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            keys.remove(key);

            // all directories are inaccessible
            if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

static void usage() {
    System.err.println("usage: java WatchDir [-r] dir");
    System.exit(-1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    interf.setVisible(true);
    interf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    File[] listeFichiers = File.listRoots();

    for( File leFichier : listeFichiers){
        String leChemin = leFichier.getAbsolutePath() ;

        //if ( ( !leChemin.equals("F:\\")) && ( !leChemin.equals("D:\\"))
          //      && ( !leChemin.equals("E:\\"))){
        Manage_Thread_Directories gestNotif 
                    = new Manage_Thread_Directories(leChemin);
        gestNotif.start();
        //}

    }
    //writeEvent.close();
}



private void createDataLink(){
    try {

        String userLogged = System.getProperty("user.name");


        File dir = new File("c:/Users/"+userLogged+"/NotesDeletedFiles");
        if( !dir.exists()){
            System.out.println(dir.mkdir());
        }

        File dataFile = new File("c:/Users"
                + "/"+userLogged+"/NotesDeletedFiles/Data.in");
        if (!dataFile.exists()){
            dataFile.createNewFile();
        }

        writeEvent = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                "c:/Users/"+userLogged+"/NotesDeletedFiles/Data.in", true)));


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Listen_Directory.class.getName()).
                log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}

private String checkIfIsInRecycleBin(String chaine) {
    String resu = chaine;
    String tab[] = chaine.split("\\\\");

    for(int i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
        if (tab[i].length() > 2){
            String ch = tab[i];
            if (ch.startsWith("$REC")){
                resu = "Recycle bin" + 
                        "\\"+tab[ tab.length -1 ] ;
                break ;
                //return resu ;
            }
        }


    }

    return resu ;        
}
```

}

public class Manage_Thread_Directories extends Thread {
    private String cheminAcces = "";

```
public Manage_Thread_Directories(String leChemin) {
    this.cheminAcces = leChemin ;
}

@Override
public void run() {



     String faire = "-r";
    if (cheminAcces.length() == 0 )
        usage();
    boolean recursive = false;

    if (faire.equals("-r")) {
        //if (cheminAcces.length() < 2)
          //  usage();
        recursive = true;

    }

    // register directory and process its events
    Path dir = Paths.get(cheminAcces);
    try {
        new Listen_Directory(dir, recursive).processEvents();

        //super.run(); 
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Manage_Thread_Directories.class.getName()).
                log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Those are source code I made. But I can not have notification from "C:/" partition when I delete files from it. Please, how can I resolve it ? Thanks